# Accessing same db.session across different modules in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, api, session, sqlalchemy, crud

I am very new to sqlalchemy and am trying to figure out how to get things cleaner and connecting.

I have created a /model base.py doc where I have created a session and established all my entities in tables (along with relationships and etc.). I want to create another module in which I operate CRUD operations on the entities (tables) in base.py. This file is called object.py and has the class BaseAPI(object) and has the different functions "create" "read" "update" and "delete". I want to make sure that I am connecting to my table (base.py) in object.py and operating on the entity User. For this case, the entity (table) is Users.

This is what I have in the API object.py doc:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import notssdb.model
from base import User #importing from the module base.py -- doesn't work

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///./notssdb.db', echo=True) #in-memory sql engine 

# create a Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class BaseAPI(object):
#    DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine))
#    users = DBSession.query(User).all()

    def __init__ (self):
       session = Session()


# CREATE USER 

    def create_user(self, username, password, fullname):
        new_user = User(username, password, fullname)
        self.session.commit(new_user)
        print(username, password, fullname)
```

Am I importing too many things? Do I need to import all the sqlalchemy tools? Does my **init** constructor under class BaseAPI need to instantiate the DB session?

Answer (score 7):

**1. Am I importing too many things? Do I need to import all the sqlalchemy tools?**

Sqlalchemy doesn't have it's own coding style, you've to follow [Python coding style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). If you don't use any module there is no point of importing it.

I don't see this has been used `from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref` and this should be used while defining `models`, hence you don't need to import these modules.

**2. Does my init constructor under class BaseAPI need to instantiate the
    DB session?**

There is no hard rule that you've initiate `session` in your BaseAPI, you can even write your programme like this..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import notssdb.model
from base import User #importing from the module base.py -- doesn't work

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///./notssdb.db', echo=True) #in-memory sql engine 

# create a Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


class BaseAPI(object):

# CREATE USER 

    def create_user(self, username, password, fullname):
        new_user = User(username, password, fullname)
        session.commit(new_user)
        print(username, password, fullname)
```

But it's not good practice to club your `connection` generation part with `user manager`, I would suggest you follow  this way..

**Note:**  This is just a sample code and I didn't execute this, you just have to follow this to `structure` your code.

First create seperate module for connection management, may be like `connection_manager.py` with the below content.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///./notssdb.db', echo=True)

# create a Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class SessionManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = Session()
```

And the create your `user_manger.py` and import your `SessionManager` here.

```
from base import User # this is your User model
from connection_manager import SessionManager

class UserManager(SessionManager):

    def create_user(self, username, password, fullname):
        new_user = User(username, password, fullname)
        self.session.commit(new_user)
        print(username, password, fullname)

    def delete_user(self, *args):
        pass # your code
```

This way you can make your code cleaner.

Comment: Why did you place `Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)` outside of the class `SessionManager`?